# Python / Pandas / Data Frame / Calculate date difference

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calculation

I have a data Frame, and I am doing the following:

```
def calculate_planungsphase(audit, phase1, phase2):

datum_first_milestone = data_audit[(data_audit.Audit == audit) & (data_audit.Meilenstein == phase1)]
datum_second_milestone = data_audit[(data_audit.Audit == audit) & (data_audit.Meilenstein == phase2)]

print(datum_first_milestone['GeplantesErledigungsdatum'])
print(datum_second_milestone['GeplantesErledigungsdatum'])

print(datum_first_milestone['GeplantesErledigungsdatum'] - datum_second_milestone['GeplantesErledigungsdatum'])
```

The result of print(datum_first_milestone['GeplantesErledigungsdatum']) =

**2018-01-01
Name: GeplantesErledigungsdatum, dtype: datetime64[ns]**

The result of print(datum_second_milestone['GeplantesErledigungsdatum']) =

**2018-01-02 Name: GeplantesErledigungsdatum, dtype: datetime64[ns]**

The result of the difference calculation is:

**0   NaT
1   NaT
Name: GeplantesErledigungsdatum, dtype: timedelta64[ns**

Why is the result of the calculation NaT? And why do i have two results, when I am doing only one calculation? (Index 0 and Index 1 = NaT)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem different index values, so in subtraction `Series` are not aligned.

Possible solution, if same size of both filtered `Series`, is create same index values:

```
datum_first_milestone.index = datum_second_milestone.index
```

Also solution should be simplify if need filter only column by `loc` + `column name`:

```
datum_first_milestone = data_audit.loc[(data_audit.Audit == audit) & (data_audit.Meilenstein == phase1), 'GeplantesErledigungsdatum']
datum_second_milestone = data_audit.loc[(data_audit.Audit == audit) & (data_audit.Meilenstein == phase2), 'GeplantesErledigungsdatum']

print(datum_first_milestone)
print(datum_second_milestone)
```

and if always is returned one value [`Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) return scalars:

```
print (datum_first_milestone.item() - datum_second_milestone.item())
```

More general if there is one or more values is possible select first value for scalars:

```
print (datum_first_milestone.iat[0] - datum_second_milestone.iat[0])
```